# Print Column Value if exists if not null using Dynamic SQL (Cursor)

Tags: plsql

I am trying to print a value if a column exists for the table (AEFM)
RD_DataDictionary table has all the tablenames and columnnames.
Dictionary table has AEECILIT, AEREL1IT, AESEQIT AND 2-3 MORE COLUMNS

so, if a column exists in RD_DataDicitionary table print the value for it using the columnname from it in the AEFM select statement below and if not it will be NULL as ColumnName.

I am getting all the null as columnname even though some of them are in the table.

```
DECLARE
    v_tablename VARCHAR2(100) := 'AEFM';
    v_sql_query VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_column_list VARCHAR2(4000) := '';

    -- Declare a list of columns to check
    TYPE column_list_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
    v_columns column_list_type := 
        column_list_type('AESEQIT', 'AEECILIT', 'AEREL1IT', 'AEREL2IT', 'AEREL3IT', 'AEREL4IT', 
                         'AEREL5IT', 'AEREL6IT', 'AEREL7IT', 'AEREL8IT', 'AEREL9IT', 
                         'AEREL10IT', 'AESAEIT');

BEGIN
    -- Loop through the list of columns
    FOR i IN 1..v_columns.COUNT LOOP
        -- Check if the column exists in the dictionary table
        v_sql_query :=
            'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RD_DataDictionary ' ||
            'WHERE tablename = :TABLENAME AND columnname = :COLUMNNAME';

        DECLARE
            v_result NUMBER;
        BEGIN
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql_query 
            INTO v_result USING v_tablename, v_columns(i);

            -- Append the column to the list with NULL if it doesn't exist
            v_column_list := v_column_list || 
                CASE WHEN v_result > 0 THEN v_columns(i) ELSE 'NULL' END ||
                ' AS ' || v_columns(i) || ', ';
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error checking column ' || v_columns(i) || ': ' || SQLERRM);
        END;
    END LOOP;

    -- Remove the trailing comma and space
    v_column_list := RTRIM(v_column_list, ', ');

    -- Construct the dynamic SQL query
    v_sql_query := 'SELECT ' || v_column_list || ' FROM BA.MK4482010_INF_DEV.' || v_tablename;

    -- Display the generated SQL query
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Generated SQL Query: ' || v_sql_query);

    -- Execute the dynamic SQL query (you may add additional logic here)
    -- EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql_query;
END;
/
```

Comment: Please add some sample data and desired output for it. It's hard to tell what is the issue with the **data processing** when there's no data to test.